# What effect does LPIM have on virtual memory

Tags: windows, windows-10, pagefile, client-server, windows-11

When LPIM is enabled it prevents paging out to virtual memory which causes pages to remain in ram.

My question is:

when LockPagesInMemory is enabled is the pagefile still being used some how or should you just disable the pagefile?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable Lock Pages in Memory only specific apps can use it. And most of the apps should not be pinned in memory because you need it for OS, caching, etc. So AFAIK you should not disable paging file. And you should not enable Lock Pages in Memory if you are not 100% sure you need this and you will benefit from it.